# Convert a datetime object

Tags: python, datetime

In Python how do I convert a `datetime` object like `datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 18, 22, 21, 45, 277000)` to something like `"Sun Dec 18 2010 22:21:45 GMT+0000 (UTC)"`?

Comment: There's a trick to this.  It's called search.  If you search for "formatting datetime" you'll find hundreds of copies of your exact question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python, Convert 9 tuple UTC date to MySQL datetime format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686717/python-convert-9-tuple-utc-date-to-mysql-datetime-format)

Answer (score 3):

You can use strftime for this purpose. Read more [here](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime.strptime#strftime-strptime-behavior).

Not sure about utc offset, but seems that you can use something like this:

```
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 18, 22, 21, 45, 277000)
d.strftime("%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S %z")
>>> Sat Dec 18 2010 22:21:45
```

Where using the link above:

- %a - Locale’s abbreviated weekday name
- %b - Locale’s abbreviated month name
- %d - Day of the month as a decimal number [01,31]
- %H - Hour (24-hour clock) as a decimal number [00,23]
- %M - Minute as a decimal number [00,59]
- %S - Second as a decimal number [00,61]
- %z - UTC offset in the form +HHMM or -HHMM (empty string if the the
  object is naive)